# Changing textarea's border color onselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there an onselect for textarea in css? I'm trying to change the border color of the textarea to red onselect instead of the default blue. How would I do that, in css, or html, if that's possible? If not, any other method's fine too.

```css
textarea {
resize: none;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows = '4' cols = '50' placeholder = 'Add a new comment...'></textarea>
```

Comment: You mean `onfocus`? Or do you actually mean when selecting text in the textarea? There is no `onselect` for textareas, so please describe what you try to do instead of just referring to a non-exisiting event.

Comment: @GolezTrol You realized that I asked if there was such a method for textareas, right?

Comment: I acknowledged that, I'm just saying that 'onselect' isn't a clear description, and I asked you to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `focus` and `border` to change the border color. Don't forget to set `outline: none` as well.

```
textarea:focus {
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/tv4zwpn0/

Comment: the forgotten brother of border :))

Comment: @madalinivascu We should erase his existence.

Comment: @frosty That's exactly what `outline: none !important;` does :)

Comment: Cool. What does !important does?

Comment: And also, since we're here, do you know how to make the placeholder disappear onfocus as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use the :focus selector and disable any outline with `outline: none;`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ugspwmg/)

```css
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea:focus {
  border-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows = '4' cols = '50' placeholder = 'Add a new comment...'></textarea>
```